# plot multiple XTS timeseries by day only

Tags: r, plot, time-series, xts

i have a question with plotting (time series) in R and I hope someone can give me some suggestions:

I have an R project (latest version) where i want to compare the river outflow with precipitation and other climate factors. This I want to do by seasons and/or monthes. However, when i want to plot my data, R creates the X axis by monthes. To put all data (monthes) in one plot my thoughts are that the x axis shows the days of the monthes, only and the y axis the liter/s. But how to change the behavior of R concerning the x axis?

---

Here is my example data (50 datasets):

```
outflow = outflow_orig[sample(nrow(outflow_orig),50),]

show(outflow)
                datum liter_s
939        03.12.2012   16.40
422        31.01.2008   53.62
1373       18.02.2016   37.34
997        28.06.2013  117.20
719        30.07.2010   50.62
1253       09.06.2015   57.36
79         19.11.2004   21.62
1012       31.08.2013   60.28
745        08.11.2010   37.96
562        05.03.2009   77.28
15         27.12.2003   18.47
730        03.09.2010   45.93
1150       16.10.2014   18.47
460        12.06.2008   48.79
104     03.02.2005-na   26.66
504        20.11.2008   17.46
1048       11.01.2014   41.12
1241       09.05.2015   61.03
763        04.01.2011   49.47
1146       02.10.2014   18.47
1224       04.04.2015   66.36
909        19.07.2012   31.71
155        27.04.2005   75.87
147        12.04.2005   71.96
889        30.04.2012   59.35
268        09.06.2006   64.70
797        11.04.2011   59.65
932        02.11.2012   17.97
657        08.01.2010   41.93
113        11.12.2003   19.43
226        05.01.2006   26.31
396        06.11.2007   20.26
82         03.12.2004   20.35
1062       21.02.2014   39.29
299        09.11.2006   23.11
1264       09.07.2015   47.15
152  21.04.2005-17.15   81.40
665        11.02.2010   48.90
348        12.04.2007   53.17
407        11.12.2007   32.53
648        25.12.2009   36.46
785        24.02.2011   81.10
1331       01.12.2015   18.96
711        07.07.2010   46.40
498        31.10.2008   17.66
1489       26.10.2016   19.43
606        22.07.2009   46.85
496        23.10.2008   17.97
1120       18.08.2014   16.93
946        23.12.2012   23.47
```

---

An XTS object is created because sometimes i have two measurements per day and characters in the dataset.

```
outflow.xts     <- apply.daily(xts(outflow$liter_s, order.by = strptime(outflow$datum, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "")),"mean", na.rm=TRUE)
outflow.df <- data.frame(date=index(outflow.xts), coredata(outflow.xts))

str(outflow.df)
'data.frame':   1456 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Datum     : Date, format: "2003-11-05" "2003-11-09" "2003-11-12" ...
 $ liter_s: num  19.9 19.9 23.5 19.4 19.4 ...
```

---

Monthes/seasons are extracted :

```
january    = outflow.xts[.indexmon(outflow.xts) %in% c(0)]
summer     = outflow.xts[.indexmon(outflow.xts) %in% c(6,7,8)]
```

2nd: climate data:

```
klimadaten <- read.csv(file="Klimastation_Langensallach-2003-2016-LFL_Bayern.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ";", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
klimadaten$datum  = as.Date(klimadaten$datum, format("%d.%m.%Y"))
klimadaten[,2:7]  = apply(klimadaten[,2:7], 2, as.numeric)
# Remove NA    
klimadaten = klimadaten[complete.cases(klimadaten[, 6]),]

str(klimadaten)
'data.frame':   4580 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ datum          : Date, format: "2003-11-01" "2003-11-02" "2003-11-03" ...
 $ eistag         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ frosttag       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ temp_luft_2m   : num  6.52 5.43 7.77 7.9 6.04 5.2 3.94 5.63 5.28 1.46 ...
 $ niederschlag_mm: num  0.7 0.1 0.3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 ...
 $ temp_boden_5cm : num  6.39 6.19 6.25 6.68 5.69 5.2 5.08 4.97 4.77 4.52 ...
 $ luftfeuchte_rel: num  91.9 87.7 82 83.8 81.7 ...

head(klimadaten)
       datum eistag frosttag temp_luft_2m niederschlag_mm temp_boden_5cm luftfeuchte_rel
1 2003-11-01      0        0         6.52             0.7           6.39           91.93
2 2003-11-02      0        0         5.43             0.1           6.19           87.73
3 2003-11-03      0        0         7.77             0.3           6.25           82.03
4 2003-11-04      0        0         7.90             0.0           6.68           83.84
5 2003-11-05      0        0         6.04             0.0           5.69           81.74
6 2003-11-06      0        0         5.20             0.0           5.20           68.53
```

And now my really basic knowledge in R ends.... How can i plot the outflow-monthes in one graph and 2nd how can i plot the seasons and subsets of the refering climate data?

Really, thank you for any help and suggestings.

Kind regards from Germany
Sascha

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. It is good you show the data with `head()`, but we cannot easily pick it up and use it demonstrate possible solutions. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Hello Eric Fail, tthe only thing i missed to write is the original data. I can place some raw data from it here:

Comment: I think the link got lost in translation. Not that it's recommended to make _minimal_ reproducible example [emphasis added]. It often happens that one finds the bug when constructing the reproducible example. At lest that often happens for me.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got the solution for my problem. The funktion fortify() helped me to extract the value AND the index from the XTS in a new dataframe. With 2 values i am able to create a plot like i know it.
This question can be "closed" now (if this is possible).
Kind regards